# Comment formuler clairement le fait qu’on a oublié de tourner sur une rue à l’occasion d’une course de taxi?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, transports

***Ajout de « Je vous prie de bien vouloir m’excuser » à toutes les formulations proposées.

Je devais tourner à gauche, mais cela m’est sorti de l’esprit.

Je devais prendre cette voie mais, par inadvertance, je suis allé tout droit.

Je devais emprunter la voie devant laquelle on vient de passer, mais en raison d’une distraction, j’ai continué sur cette voie.

La formulation « tourner à gauche » me rend hésitant, en ce qu’elle semble sonnée à l’oreille, mais qu’aucune référence linguistique en fait mention, d’où mon hésitation.

Merci!

Comment: Pourrais-tu dire quand tu emploies ces phrases ?  C'est quand tu conduis, quand tu es toujours sur le chemin ?

Comment: Clarification: Sur le chemin, sur le moment.

Comment: « Cela fait longtemps que je ne suis pas venu dans ce quartier, il me semble que j'aurais dû tourner ici, ah oui. c'est cela. Je vais faire demi-tour à la prochaine … » — On n'affole pas le client, on ne se met pas en situation de faiblesse, on a la solution pour surmonter cet incident bénin — À mettre dans une situation du siècle passé, impossible avec le GPS de nos jours :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première formulation est une possibilité correcte et peut-être bien la meilleure.

- Je devais tourner à gauche, mais cela m’est sorti de l’esprit.

La seconde est aussi correcte mais la référence à la voie doit apparaitre dans le contexte.

- Je devais prendre une voie que l'on vient de passer mais, par inadvertance, je suis allé tout droit. (*par exemple*)

Dans la troisième option, la référence de « cette » n'est pas clairement « la voie utilisée » et il vaut mieux changer cela et dire « et j'ai continué tout droit ».

- Je devais emprunter la voie devant laquelle on vient de passer, mais en raison d’une distraction, j’ai continué tout droit.

« Tourner à gauche » et « tourner à droite », pour répéter ce qui a été dit dans la réponse de user livresque, est tout à fait correct. Ce qui n'est pas correct c'est « tourner sur une rue » ; on ne dit que « tourner dans une rue /dans la rue X » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tourner+sur+la+rue%2Ctourner+dans+la+rue%2Ctourner+dans+une+rue%2Ctourner+sur+une+rue&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctourner%20dans%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctourner%20dans%20une%20rue%3B%2Cc0)).

« Sur » est cependant utilisé avec les indications de sens « gauche » et « droite » lorsque l'article défini est utilisé. Sans l'article on utilise **à**.

- tourner sur la gauche, tourner sur la droite

Answer (score 0):

« Tourner à gauche » et « tourner à droite » sont justes.  C'est utiliser l'imparfait du verbe devoir qui pose des problèmes. Si l'on est toujours dans la voiture et on a fait une faute à une intersection, le conducteur peut dire :

- J'aurais dû tourner à gauche, mais [...j'étais dans les nuages]. C'est la circulation, maintenant on roule plus vite que prévu.
- J'aurais dû prendre cette voie-là au lieu d'aller tout droit.  Pardon, je ne l'ai pas fait exprès.
- J'aurais dû prendre la voie là où on vient de passer mais....

C'est le conditionnel passé.  Cela exprime "I should have [turned/gone/done]" en anglais.

Comment: « [... j'étais dans les nuages].» « j'ai raté le virage, j'ai manqué le tournant, etc. » sont des fautes graves pour un chauffeur professionnel — « Pardon, je ***ne l'ai*** pas fait exprès. » est maladroit, on peut lui répondre, si l'on est énervé par le retard que cette erreur va entraîner : « Il ne manquerait plus que ça ! ». Il y a d'autres façons de répondre … elles sortent du cadre de la question.

Comment: @LPH Relancé les navigateurs puis le PC, Chromium OK, FireFox toujours KO — Plus de problème :-)

Comment: @Personne Merci de nouveau. Je suis d'accord mais ça arrive.  Inventer des excuses, ça fait partie du service à la clientèle, mais c'est peut-être une autre question.

Comment: @livresque … il y a une suggestion de répons dans un commentaire sous la question.

Comment: Les autres conjonctions peuvent, ou bien être répétées (surtout si les
propositions sont senties comme nettement distinctes), ou bien être reprises par « que », ou bien, plus rarement, n'être ni répétées ni reprises par « que ». (LBU, 1078 b 2°) : « et que l'on a fait une ».  You can download here: https://www.pdfdrive.com/le-bon-usage-grammaire-fran%C3%A7aise-14e-%C3%A9d-d157189845.html